# Why is the norm $1$ of matrix $A$ is equal to the maximum sum of column

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, normed-spaces, numerical-linear-algebra

first, I know that there exists a similar question to mine which is in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/519279/why-is-the-matrix-norm-a-1-maximum-absolute-column-sum-of-the-matrix), and it is actually very well explained. However, there is just one part that I do not understand. That is the conclusion. First, how did they conclude that norm of Matrix $A$ is less than the maximum column sum of matrix $A$? Then how did they conclude that it did not the inequality turned into equality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The one-norm of $A=(a_{ij})$ is defined as the maximum of $\Vert Ax\Vert_{1}$ with respect to all vectors $x$ which are unit in the one-norm.
In other words,
$$
\Vert A\Vert_{1}=\max_{\Vert x\Vert_{1}=1}\Vert Ax\Vert_{1}.
$$
In the answer you link to, the author first shows that for **any**  vector $x$ satisfying $\Vert x \Vert_1 = 1$,
$$
\Vert Ax\Vert_{1}\leq\max_{j}\sum_{i}|a_{ij}|=\sum_{i}|a_{im}|
$$
where $j=m$ is some index that maximizes the expression on the right hand side of the above inequality.
Next, the author notes that **the standard basis vector** $e_{m}$ (i.e., the vector whose $m$-th entry is 1 and whose other entries are zero) satisfies
$$
\Vert e_{m}\Vert_{1}=1\qquad\text{and}\qquad\Vert Ae_{m}\Vert_{1}=\sum_{i}|a_{im}|.
$$
Putting this all together,
$$
\sum_{i}|a_{im}|=\Vert Ae_{m}\Vert_{1}\leq\Vert A\Vert_{1}\leq\max_{j}\sum_{i}|a_{ij}|=\sum_{i}|a_{im}|.
$$
Since the leftmost and rightmost expressions are identical, it follows that all of the inequalities above must be equalities.
The desired result follows.

Comment: Probably you want to write $\vert a_{ij}\vert$ instead of $a_{ij}$.

Comment: Heyy, really like your answer, if you could help with an exercise, would really appreciate it :) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3096022/normed-vector-space-schauder-basis-exercise

Comment: @JensSchwaiger: +1. Thanks for catching that.